# How do I get the recent message in a json string

Tags: python

How do I get the recent message corresponding to reviewer":{"name":"Klocwork Automation User"

INPUT:-

```
{"project":"platform/frameworks/opt/telephony","branch":"kitkat","id":"Idcf6faee0f6259704ea07b62ce713ebdd4c5da1b","number":"739919","subject":"Correct order of parameter in iccExchangeApdu()","owner":{"name":"Satish Kumar Singh","email":"c_ssing@qca.qualcomm.com","username":"c_ssing"},"url":"https://review-android.quicinc.com/739919","createdOn":1399412660,"lastUpdated":1399418924,"sortKey":"002ce960000b4a4f","open":true,"status":"NEW","comments":[{"timestamp":1399412661,"reviewer":{"name":"Gator Service Account","email":"gator@localhost","username":"gator"},"message":"Patch Set 1: Looks good to me, but someone else must approve\n\nThis patchset has been processed by the Gator."},{"timestamp":1399412704,"reviewer":{"name":"Checkpatch Service Account","email":"checkpatch@localhost","username":"checkpatch"},"message":"Patch Set 1: Looks good to me, but someone else must approve\n\nYour change has passed all of the checks enforced by the android patchchecker."},{"timestamp":1399413456,"reviewer":{"name":"Satish Kumar Singh","email":"c_ssing@qca.qualcomm.com","username":"c_ssing"},"message":"Patch Set 1: Developer Build and Test Successful\n\n"},{"timestamp":1399415354,"reviewer":{"name":"Gueyoung Lee","email":"gueyoung@qca.qualcomm.com","username":"gueyoung"},"message":"Patch Set 1: Looks good to me, but someone else must approve\n\n"},{"timestamp":1399417092,"reviewer":{"name":"Dhananjai Singh","email":"dhananja@qca.qualcomm.com","username":"dhananja"},"message":"Patch Set 1: Looks good to me, but someone else must approve\n\n"},{"timestamp":1399417366,"reviewer":{"name":"David Ng","email":"dng@quicinc.com","username":"dng"},"message":"Patch Set 1: Looks good to me, approved\n\nI remembered the previous change went in recently.  How come this was not caught in the original testing as this would have failed right away?\n\nThanks!\nDavid"},{"timestamp":1399418880,"reviewer":{"name":"Klocwork Automation User","email":"kwuser@localhost","username":"kwuser"},"message":"Patch Set 1:\n\nThis change is being verified in klocwork for the following manifests along with other changes as detailed below:\n\n\n\n\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\n\ngit-android.quicinc.com/platform/manifest:kk:default.xml\n\n\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\n\nhttps://commander.qualcomm.com/commander/pages/SimplifiedJobView/LoadComponent_run?jobId\u003d3217513\n\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,\n\n\n\nPlease note that verification of all changes in this batch need to be successful before this change can be merged.\n\nPLEASE DO NOT UPLOAD A NEW PATCH SET, OR REMOVE APPROVALS UNTIL THE VERIFICATION IS COMPLETE.\n"},{"timestamp":1399418898,"reviewer":{"name":"Linux Build Service Account","email":"lnxbuild@localhost","username":"lnxbuild"},"message":"Patch Set 1:\n\nThis change is being verified in lookahead for the following manifests along with other changes as detailed below:\n\n\n\n\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\n\ngit-android.quicinc.com/platform/manifest:kk:default.xml\n\n\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\n\nhttps://commander.qualcomm.com/commander/pages/SimplifiedJobView/LoadComponent_run?jobId\u003d3217515\n\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,739919\n\n\n\nPlease note that verification of all changes in this batch need to be successful before this change can be merged.\n\nPLEASE DO NOT UPLOAD A NEW PATCH SET, OR REMOVE APPROVALS UNTIL THE VERIFICATION IS COMPLETE.\n"},{"timestamp":1399418924,"reviewer":{"name":"Linux Build Service Account","email":"lnxbuild@localhost","username":"lnxbuild"},"message":"Patch Set 1:\n\nThis change is being verified in lookahead for the following manifests along with other changes as detailed below:\n\n\n\n\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\n\ngit-android.quicinc.com/platform/manifest:kk:default.xml\n\n\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\u003d\n\nhttps://commander.qualcomm.com/commander/pages/SimplifiedJobView/LoadComponent_run?jobId\u003d3217517\n\n--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n\n  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,739919\n\n\n\nPlease note that verification of all changes in this batch need to be successful before this change can be merged.\n\nPLEASE DO NOT UPLOAD A NEW PATCH SET, OR REMOVE APPROVALS UNTIL THE VERIFICATION IS COMPLETE.\n"}]}
    {"type":"stats","rowCount":1,"runTimeMilliseconds":3}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copied the first line of your input into `stringdata = u'''...'''`

Then load it into json

```
import json
dict_data =json.loads(stringdata.replace('\n','') )
```

You need to manually examine the data structure

```
for c in dict_data ['comments']:
    if c['reviewer']['name'].startswith('Klocwork'): # you can use exact search
        print c['message']
```

The output is:

```
Patch Set 1:This change is being verified in klocwork for the following manifests along with other changes as detailed below:=====================================================================================git-android.quicinc.com/platform/manifest:kk:default.xml=====================================================================================https://commander.qualcomm.com/commander/pages/SimplifiedJobView/LoadComponent_run?jobId=3217513--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  o https://review-android.quicinc.com/#change,Please note that verification of all changes in this batch need to be successful before this change can be merged.PLEASE DO NOT UPLOAD A NEW PATCH SET, OR REMOVE APPROVALS UNTIL THE VERIFICATION IS COMPLETE.
```